# GORM paginateParams usage problem

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-orm

I'm just trying to do pagination but until now I couldn't make it. I have 2 domain classes and one to many relationship.

```
class User {
   static hasMany = [contacts:Contact]
}

class Contact {
   static belongsTo = [ user : User ]
}
```

I have 20 Contacts.

When I tried to make a query like this :

```
def maxResult = 20

def startIndex = 0

def contacts = Contact.findAllByUser(user, [max:maxResult, offset:startIndex])
```

it  is not working. Query is working but pagination with gorm is not working. Result is just 1 contact object.

when I tried;

```
def startIndex = 0

def contacts = Contact.findAllByUser(user, [offset:startIndex])
```

Result is 20 contact object but when i tried it with different startIndex value, it is not working also. for startIndex = 5, result is also 20 ontact object.

Is there anybody have any idea about this. Maybe i am doing something wrong, maybe it is gorm's problem. I havent found the answer. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried the DynamicFinder to do this thing yet, but as I view the document, your syntax seems to be right. As an alternative, I use createCriteria to solve the paging problem.

```
def queryResult = Contact.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {
            and {
                /// FILTER ///
                user {
                    eq("id", userInstance.id)
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: When I tried groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.erimerturk.contact.model.User.call()
is applicable for argument types: (com.erimerturk.contact.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl$_getContacts_closure1_closure12_clo
sure13_closure14) values: [com.erimerturk.contact.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl$_getContacts_closure1_closure12_closure13_c
losure14@1fd0cc]|Possible solutions: save(), wait(), any(), getAll(), save(java.util.Map), save(java.lang.Boolean)

Comment: @erimeturk: the error message looks strange. It may mean there's something not right in the domain class, although your model looks alright. You may try command "grails clean", then re-compile again.

Comment: @erimeturk: I have add a "}" to get rid of the syntax error in my code.

Comment: @Hoàng Long: I have already added it, but problem is not that i think. I tried clean and re-compile but everything is same. It is very strange because when i tried it with DynamicFinder, the filter part is working. There is no exception.

Comment: @erimeturk: excuse me, where's exactly you try this code? I just remember that dynamic finder and createCriteria doesn't work well in unit test.

Comment: @Hoàng Long: not in unit test. I am using jetty as server and also i am using maven to manage my project. I am making get request from a rest client to my server.

Comment: @erimeturk: sorry, but I'm going to make a guess here: is there any 'user' local variable in the scope of the query? For example, there's a 'user\ variable in the controller where you call dynamic finder.

Comment: @erimeturk: it's my fault, I've put a 'user' variable in my code in the first place. It's because Groovy can't identify between 2 'user' closure, so I have updated the code.

Comment: @Hoàng Long: you are right for user scope problem. i changed the name, it worked. But pagination problem is going on.     

Contact.createCriteria().list{
    and {
     user {
      eq("id", shadowUser.id)
     }
    }
   }
when i made a query like this , it returned 17241 objects but all of them is 'contact1'. i have just 2 different contact. So it's impossible. 

After change query,
'Contact.createCriteria().list(max: count, offset: startIndex)'
it returned same 'contact1' objects again. The number of object is same with count. for count= 500
it returned 500 and count= 500
it returned 500.

Comment: @erimeturk: well, here we are at the heart of the problem. Your result is the join result between the User and Contact table. The createCriteria/dynamic finder used to have some bugs, but it seems to be alright for recent versions of Grails. My Grails version is 1.3.6. Otherwise, you may try using listDistinct or pure HQL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905476/gorm-createcriteria-and-list-do-not-return-the-same-results-what-can-i-do) or try changing the fetching mode(http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/duplicate-entries-in-list-on-eager-fetchmode-td1347093.html)

Comment: @Hoàng Long: thanks for your help, i solve my problem with using pure HQL, i think Grails 1.3.5 Criteria/dynamic finder have some bugs.   This query worked and i solve my pagination problem.  Contact.executeQuery("from Contact c where c.user =:pUser",  [pUser:shadowUser],[max: counter, offset: startIndex, sort: "id",order: "asc"]). Thanks too much again @Hoàng Long.

Comment: @erimeturk: not at all, thanks for the problem, too ;). I learn quite a bit from it.