# Return unique results when using findAllBy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following method in a service, please note the `.user` on the `def usersByRole` line:

```
def getUsersByRole(String desiredRole1, String desiredRole2, String desiredRole3) {
    Role role1 = Role.findByAuthority(desiredRole1)
    Role role2 = Role.findByAuthority(desiredRole2)
    Role role3 = Role.findByAuthority(desiredRole3)
    def usersByRole = UserRole.findAllByRoleInList([role1, role2, role3]).user
    return usersByRole
}
```

It works good, but when a user has multiple roles (i.e. `ROLE_ADMIN`, and `ROLE_OWNER`) then that user exists twice in the collection if both of the previously mentioned roles are given as parameters.  Is there any clean way I can make the collection contain only unique results?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A similar question as yours can be found here: [GORM createCriteria and list do not return the same results : what can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905476/gorm-createcriteria-and-list-do-not-return-the-same-results-what-can-i-do)

### Method 1

If you want to return unique list of users directly from DB query then you can use `listDistinct` on `User` (supposing that user has a `roles` OneToMany association with `UserRoles`)

```
User.createCriteria().listDistinct {
    roles {
       in 'role', [role1, role2, role3]
    }
}
```

### Method 2

You can also try to query `UserRole` directly and group by User using the `groupProperty` (see http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

### Method 3

Remove duplicated users from the returned list:

```
UserRole.findAllByRoleInList([role1, role2, role3])*.user.unique()
```

Comment: Method 3 works great for my purposes, though I did remove the `*` (why exactly do you have the `*` there anyway). I search for such a method in the API before I posted, but only found [this](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html). Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The `*` is the spread operator (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators), it's a shortcut for `collect`, ex: `object*.method()` is the same as `object.collect{ it.method()}`. Groovy has another shortcut on it that many people don't know about where if you don't call a method, but instead call a property, you don't need the spread operator (so `roleList.user` will get all the users for all the roles, but `roleList.getUser()` would fail without the spread operator).  You can omit it if you, and the others that will read the code, know what's going on, otherwise, it's more idiomatic to leave it in.

Answer (score 2):

The finder will return a `List`, and calling `.user` also returns a `List`, but you can cheat and cast it to a `Set` and it will remove duplicates. Since there's no order needed (you're returning `def` so it doesn't appear that you care about the collection type) you don't need to convert it back:

```
def getUsersByRole(String desiredRole1, String desiredRole2, String desiredRole3) {
    Role role1 = Role.findByAuthority(desiredRole1)
    Role role2 = Role.findByAuthority(desiredRole2)
    Role role3 = Role.findByAuthority(desiredRole3)
    return UserRole.findAllByRoleInList([role1, role2, role3]).user as Set
}
```

This presumes that you have a well-defined `equals` and `hashCode` in your `User` class so the uniqueness check makes sense.

Comment: That is a nice trick, but it would be nice to have my results in order. I'm also not sure what exactly you mean by when you are talking about "well-defined equals and hashCode", but I would like to know :)  Right now I am using `unique()` and it seems to do what I want. Thanks for your input!