# PagedResultList .size() and .getTotalCount() return different values in grails gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following code

```
PagedResultList res = myService.getPage(paginateParams, ...)
println res.size() // returns 2
println res.getTotalCount() // returns 1
```

getPage looks like:

```
def criteria = MyDomain.createCriteria()
criteria.list(max: paginateParams.max, offset: paginateParams.offset) { // max is 10, offset is 0, sortBy is updatedAt and sortOrder is desc
    eq('org', org)
    order(paginateParams.sortBy, paginateParams.sortOrder)
}
```

why do the two method return different values? The documentation doesn't explain the difference, but does mention that getTotalCount is for number of records

currently on grails 2.4.5

edits:

println on res prints out:

```
res: [
com.<hidden>.MyDomain: 41679f98-a7c5-4193-bba8-601725007c1a, 
com.<hidden>.MyDomain: 41679f98-a7c5-4193-bba8-601725007c1a]
```

Yes, res has a SINGLE object twice - that's the bug I'm trying to fix.  How do I know that? I  have an primary key on MyDomain's ID, and when I inspect the database, it's also showing one record for this particular org (see my criteria)

edit 2:  I found this comment (http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

> listDistinct  If subqueries or associations are used, one may end up
>   with the same row multiple times in the result set. In Hibernate one
>   would do a "CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY". In Grails one
>   can do it by just using this method.

Which, if I understand correctly, is their way of saying "list" method doesn't work in this scenario, use listDistinct instead but then they go on to warn:

> The listDistinct() method does not work well with the pagination
>   options maxResult and firstResult. If you need distinct results with
>   pagination, we currently recommend that you use HQL. You can find out
>   more information from this blog post.

However, the blog post is a dead link.

Related: [GORM createCriteria and list do not return the same results : what can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905476/gorm-createcriteria-and-list-do-not-return-the-same-results-what-can-i-do)

Comment: could you print full content of res ?

Comment: @WallSkyBlue done, edited my original post

Comment: umm... I guess your number didn't match because of duplicate but this worse than I think LOL, sorry no idea about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing related issues ([GORM createCriteria and list do not return the same results : what can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905476/gorm-createcriteria-and-list-do-not-return-the-same-results-what-can-i-do)) I determined that there were several approaches:

1. Use grails projection groupBy('id') - doesn't work b/c i need the entire object
2. USe HSQL - Domain.executeQuery - actually this didn't work for my scenario very well because this returns a list, whereas criteria.list returns a PagedResultList from which I previously got totalCount.  This solution had me learning HSQL and also made me break up my existing logic into two components - one that returned PagedResultList and one that didn't
3. Simply keep a set of IDs as I process my PagedResultList and make sure that I didn't have any duplicates.

I ended up going with option 3 because it was quick, didn't require me to learn a new language (HSQL) and I felt that I could easily write the code to do it and I'm not limited by the CPU to do such a unique ID check.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to actual problem after question edited but this quote seems useful

> Generally PagedResultList `.size()` perform size() on resultList property (in-memory object represent database record), while `.getTotalCount()` do count query against database. If this two value didn't match your list may contain duplicate.